# Does adwhirl do a lot of work in the background?

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl, slowdown

I added adwhirl to my application with admob and mdotm and now it is freezing up and giving me keydispatch errors. I know those are from it trying to do too much in the background but it was not happening before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was just my phone being low on memory and some other hardware factors.